# How to activate conda environment in GitHub Actions?

Tags: installation, conda, github-actions, environment, samtools

I am setting up continuous integration using GitHub Actions. One of the prerequisites (`samtools`) is most easily installed by `conda`. The standard way to use installed packages is to activate the corresponding `conda` environment. **I am looking for a way to activate the `conda` environment.** The common methods to activate it failed, see details below. My current workaround is to add to the `PATH` a hardcoded path to `samtools`, installed by `conda`. But this is not maintainable if the number of installed packages increases. It is also not the standard way to use packages installed with `conda`.

**DETAILS:**

**`.github/workflows/conda.yml`**

```yml
name: Conda
on: [push]

jobs:
  # label of the job
  tests:
    name: Tests
    # containers must run in Linux based operating systems
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Docker Hub image that `postgres-job` executes in
    container: node:latest
    # service containers to run with `postgres-job`
    steps:
      - uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
        with:
          miniconda-version: "latest"
          channels: bioconda, conda-forge, defaults
          use-only-tar-bz2: true  # IMPORTANT: This needs to be set for caching to work properly!
          auto-update-conda: true
          auto-activate-base: true
      - name: Install samtools
        run: |
            set -x

            echo "begin: PATH=$PATH;"

            conda create -y --name samtools samtools

            conda activate samtools || true
            echo "after conda activate samtools: PATH=$PATH;"
            which samtools || true
              
            $CONDA/bin/activate samtools || true
            echo "after CONDA/bin/activate samtools: PATH=$PATH;"
            which samtools || true
              
            export PATH="3/envs/samtools/bin:$PATH"
            echo "after export PATH=3/envs/samtools/bin:PATH: PATH=$PATH;"
            which samtools || true
```

**Output:**

```
Run set -x
begin: PATH=3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
+ echo begin: PATH=3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
+ conda create -y --name samtools samtools
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
[...]

# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate samtools
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
+ conda activate samtools
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run
    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell
See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
+ true
after conda activate samtools: PATH=3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
+ echo after conda activate samtools: PATH=3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
+ which samtools
+ true
+ 3/bin/activate samtools
+ echo after CONDA/bin/activate samtools: PATH=3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
+ which samtools
after CONDA/bin/activate samtools: PATH=3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
+ true
after export PATH=3/envs/samtools/bin:PATH: PATH=3/envs/samtools/bin:3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
+ export PATH=3/envs/samtools/bin:3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ echo after export PATH=3/envs/samtools/bin:PATH: PATH=3/envs/samtools/bin:3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
+ which samtools
3/envs/samtools/bin/samtools
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Automatic Activation

The documentation also gives examples of automatic activation. Specifically, [Example #3](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-miniconda#example-3-other-options) demonstrates this with a couple key components:

1. As noted in [the IMPORTANT section](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-miniconda#important) of the documentation and in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72704717/570918), the shell needs to use login mode, which can be set globally within a job, using

```yaml
jobs:
  example-3:
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}
```

2. An environment definition is provided to `setup-miniconda` GHA. In the example it's `etc/example-environment.yml`, which defines the environment `anaconda-client-env` and this is set to activate using the `activate-environment` argument.

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
        with:
          activate-environment: anaconda-client-env
          environment-file: etc/example-environment.yml
          auto-activate-base: false
      - run: |
          conda info
          conda list
```

### Samtools Example

[image: so-samtools]

I have a repository where I test environment definitions, so here's an explicit example for `samtools`. Note that I prefer Mamba, and also recommend capturing an explicit `mamba env export` to document the environment.

[**envs/so-samtools.yaml**](https://github.com/mfansler/conda-envs-testing/blob/main/envs/so-samtools.yaml)

```yaml
name: so-samtools
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - samtools
```

[**.github/workflows/so-samtools.yaml**](https://github.com/mfansler/conda-envs-testing/blob/main/.github/workflows/so-samtools.yaml)

```yaml
name: so-samtools
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'envs/so-samtools.yaml'
      - '.github/workflows/so-samtools.yaml'

jobs:
  create-env:
    name: ${{ matrix.os }} 
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}
        
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
        
    steps:
      - name: checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: create environment with mamba
        uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
        with:
          mamba-version: "*"
          channels: conda-forge,bioconda,defaults
          auto-activate-base: false
          activate-environment: so-samtools
          environment-file: envs/so-samtools.yaml
      
      - name: check solution
        run: |
          mamba env export
      
      - name: test samtools
        run: |
          which samtools
          samtools help
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to not ignore `bash` profile files (fix from: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-miniconda ):

```yml
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}
```

**Complete GitHub Action `yml` file, `.github/workflows/conda.yml`:**

```yml
name: Conda
on: [push]

jobs:
  # label of the job
  tests:
    name: Tests
    # containers must run in Linux based operating systems
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Do not ignore bash profile files. From:
    # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-miniconda
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}
    # Docker Hub image that `postgres-job` executes in
    container: node:latest
    # service containers to run with `postgres-job`
    steps:
      - uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
        with:
          miniconda-version: "latest"
          channels: bioconda, conda-forge, defaults
          use-only-tar-bz2: true  # IMPORTANT: This needs to be set for caching to work properly!
          auto-update-conda: true
          auto-activate-base: true
      - name: Install samtools
        run: |
            echo "begin: PATH=$PATH;"

            conda create -y --name samtools samtools

            conda activate samtools || true
            echo "after conda activate samtools: PATH=$PATH;"
            which samtools || true
            # Use samtools here.
```

**Output:**

```
begin: PATH=/__w/ngs-aggregate_results/ngs-aggregate_results/3/envs/test/bin:/__w/ngs-aggregate_results/ngs-aggregate_results/3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
...
after conda activate samtools: PATH=/__w/ngs-aggregate_results/ngs-aggregate_results/3/envs/samtools/bin:/__w/ngs-aggregate_results/ngs-aggregate_results/3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
/__w/ngs-aggregate_results/ngs-aggregate_results/3/envs/samtools/bin/samtools
```